# How to undo/redo javascript regex .replace script?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

My goal is to be able to undo (using `ctrl + z`) a `.replace` script after it is clicked.

e.g.
`"word  sample"` will turn into `“word sample”` after clicking `Fix it` button. I need a feature so that a user can reverse this change using `ctrl + z` when they need to.

I know it's not automatically supported by the browser since this is a javascript manipulation.

Please see my code snippet to demonstrate that undo is not working after clicking `Fix it`

```js
function fixTextarea(textarea) {
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(" ,", ",")
.replace(" ;", ";")
.replace(" .", ".")
.replace("  ", " ")
.replace("   ", " ")
.replace("--", "—")
.replace(/(^|[-\u2014\s(\["])'/g, "$1\u2018")
.replace(/'/g, "\u2019")
.replace(/(^|[-\u2014/\[(\u2018\s])"/g, "$1\u201c")
.replace(/"/g, "\u201d")
};

function fixtext() {
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
textarea.select();
fixTextarea(textarea);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
var area = document.getElementById("textarea1");

var getCount = function (str, search) {
return str.split(search).length - 1;
};

var replace = function (search, replaceWith) {
if (typeof(search) == "object") {
area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
return;
}
if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
var start = area.selectionStart;
var end = area.selectionEnd;
var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
}
};

});
```

```css
textarea{
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;x;
background-color: #fafafa;
width: 30%;
height: 100px;
font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
outline: none;
}
.nbtn{
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #555555;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 9px 9px;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
color: #000000;
background-color: #e0f2f1;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nbtn:hover{
background-color: #fafafa;
}
.nbtn:active{
background-color: #e0f7fa;
transform: translateY(1px);
outline: none;
box-shadow: 1px #666666;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" spellcheck="true" onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')">"click  "Fix it" "to" see what will happen"    and try to undo me   if you can</textarea>

<br><br>

<button class="nbtn" onclick="fixtext()"> Fix it</button>
```

So in this sample I have, whenever a user clicks the `Fix it`button, the script to replace double spaces into single space and straight quotes into curly quotes will be activated.

What I have in mind and where I need help as to how to integrate this on this script is this:

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
var mapObj = {

}

jQuery(".cbtn").on("click", function(event) {
var currButtonId = jQuery(event.target).attr('id');
var mappedText = mapObj[currButtonId];

jQuery("#textarea1").focus();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, mappedText);
});
```

This will supposedly map all the button clicks so that a user can undo/redo them when they need to.

Please let me know about your suggestions. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking. If you want to support “undo” you keep a history buffer and map keys/clicks/whatever to something that knows how to take what’s in the history buffer and restore it. If it’s just text field content it’s easy; if you need to go deeper it can get tricky, fast.

Comment: Hi please see my updated question. I'm sorry if it's confusing. I hope it's better now. And yes, I get it but I'm not good with JS and would need some instructions to follow if possible.

Comment: I'm also trying to understand what you're asking and it is not quite clear to me... The problem is with reversing regex? or saving old changes history so the user can revert it when needed?

Comment: What I really need is to be able to undo/reverse my "Fix it" feature in case a user accidentally clicked it or they changed their mind. Because right now, once the "Fix it" changes are applied, it cannot be undone.

Comment: Or please try to run my code snippet again and see what I mean

Comment: Does it matter if the result is achieved by pressing ctrl+z or with a button?

Comment: It's better to have it using ctrl + z since that's the default shortcut every user knows. I got an answer earlier from someone, but he deleted the answer before I could test it.

Comment: Mapping every button press won't help you. The answer here is pretty much what Dave said: keep a copy of the string in an array/object before you do any replacement on it and return the copy if the user wants to undo. You'd probably want to limit the size of the potential store, however given that memory is now measured in gigabytes and we're talking about a text string, you could be quite generous with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code snippet below.
Instead of reversing the Regex Op, I keep a stack (the usual data structure for manage ctrl+Z ops) to hold the previous text before click the "fix it" btn.

In this type of solution, I take advantage of the way javascript works and the closure made by declaring a new function.
The stack array is captured inside the fixTextStackGen, that's way it's accessible to the function the "fixes" the text.
By adding the undo function declaration inside the fixTextStackGen the array is accessible to both the "fix it" and the "undo" ops.

See the code below:

```js
function fixTextarea(textarea) {
  textarea.value = textarea.value
    .replace(" ,", ",")
    .replace(" ;", ";")
    .replace(" .", ".")
    .replace("  ", " ")
    .replace("   ", " ")
    .replace("--", "—")
    .replace(/(^|[-\u2014\s(\["])'/g, "$1\u2018")
    .replace(/'/g, "\u2019")
    .replace(/(^|[-\u2014/\[(\u2018\s])"/g, "$1\u201c")
    .replace(/"/g, "\u201d");
}

//The new fix function
function fixTextarea2(textarea){
  textarea.value = textarea.value
      .replace(/[f|c|e|i]/gim,"b");
}

const fixTextStackGen = () => {
    let stack = [];
    let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    //Delaying the computation, now captures the 'fix' function in the closure as well as the stack array
    let doFunc = (fixFunction) => () => {
        stack.push(textarea.value)
        textarea.select();
        fixFunction(textarea);
    }

    let undoFunc = () => {
        textarea.value = 0 < stack.length ? stack.pop() : textarea.value;
    }
    return [doFunc, undoFunc]
}
const textControlFunctions = fixTextStackGen();

//extracting the 'Do' functions generator
const fixtextFuncGen = textControlFunctions[0];
//assigning the appropriate function to the specific identifiers
const fixtext1 = fixtextFuncGen(fixTextarea);
const fixtext2 = fixtextFuncGen(fixTextarea2);

//Extracting the 'Undo' function
const unfixText = textControlFunctions[1];

// define a handler
function ctrl_z_handlar(e) {

    // this would test for whichever key is 40 and the ctrl key at the same time
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 90) {
        // call your function to do the thing
        unfixText();
    }
}
// register the handler 
document.addEventListener('keyup', ctrl_z_handlar, false);

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
  var area = document.getElementById("textarea1");

  var getCount = function (str, search) {
    return str.split(search).length - 1;
  };

  var replace = function (search, replaceWith) {
    if (typeof search == "object") {
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      return;
    }
    if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
      var start = area.selectionStart;
      var end = area.selectionEnd;
      var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
      var lengthDiff =
        (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
      area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
      area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
      area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" spellcheck="true" onpaste="console.log('onpastefromhtml')">"click  "Fix it" "to" see what will happen"    and try to undo me   if you can</textarea>

    <br><br>

    <button class="nbtn" onclick="fixtext1()"> Fix it1</button>
    <button class="nbtn" onclick="fixtext2()"> Fix it2</button>
```

Keep in mind that there is no limitation on the array size and if the text wasn't changed and the user hit 'Fix it' pressing he will have to press 'ctrl+z' multiple times to see the previous text

EDIT:
To make the code more modular, we'll pass the 'fix' function as an argument to the 'fixTextStackGen' function, as follow:

```
//passing 'fix' function as an argument
const fixTextStackGen = (fixFunction) => {
    let stack = [];
    let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    let doFunc = () => {
        stack.push(textarea.value)
        textarea.select();
        fixFunction(textarea);
    }

    let undoFunc = () => {
        textarea.value = 0 < stack.length ? stack.pop() : textarea.value;
    }
    return [doFunc, undoFunc]
}

//passing 'fixTextarea' as an argument should yield with the same functionality
const textControlFunctions = fixTextStackGen(fixTextarea);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to do this. If it's not too much to ask, can you please create a demo to show this is working? Cause I tried to replace my script but it's not working for me?

Comment: Oh and just one last thing, is it possible to simply add a redo feature (ctrl + y)?

Comment: And I noticed that I can't have 2 scripts like this, so one is for this current Fix it, and the other is for removing extra line (same regex script, just different effect)? How can I tweak this code to be able to use it twice for 2 different buttons? I tried experimenting with it but I can't find how

Comment: I don't sure I understood... what do you mean 'I can't have 2 scripts like this'?
I'm assuming there's another Textarea in your site that is being used to alter the text to a different format and you want to use the method here to replicate the solution for the other Textarea as well?
If that's the case, know that the code presented above is semi-modular, the "fixing" is being done by calling the 'fixTextArea' function
I edited the code to get the 'fix' function as an argument

Comment: What I mean now is, say, I have 2 buttons. 1 is ```Fix It``` to replace double spaces with single space. Second button is ```Merge``` which will remove extra lines; merge paragraphs as one paragraph or one line. It's important to keep them separate buttons. Now I'm hoping the script for ```undo (ctrl + z```)  can work for that button as well. But it won't. I can't make it work for both, it will only work for the first script of that kind. Say, my reference for that is ```onclick="fixtext()"``` and ```onclick="fixtext2()"``` This works for the same textarea, btw

Comment: So the ```Merge``` button now uses ```.replace(/(\n|\n|)/gm,"")``` and that's the only difference I made, plus the ```fixtext2()``` which I'm not sure how to properly place.

Comment: added a fixtextarea2, see above

Comment: Thank you so much @sale108! That's a lot of help for me and my friends. I hope others can use this for their projects as well. Kudos!